# VBA Code Error "Invalid or unqualified reference"

Tags: excel, vba, vba6

I am very new to vba coding .
In the worksheet I am trying to add an additional column using macros-column (Q)by checking conditions in simultaneous columns  J,K,O).So if certain conditions pass in each of the columns I want a value to be entered in Q column for the respective row. This is the piece of code I put together .

```
Option Explicit

Sub Button2_Click()

Sheet1.Activate

Dim i As Long
    
    For i = 2 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    'Check so that we only process non-empty cells
    '(just in case there is an empty cell part-way through the data)
        If Cells(i, 10).Value = "No" And Cells(i, 15) <= 0 Then
        Cells(i, 17) = "Pending with employee"
        Else
        If Cells(i, 10).Value = "No" And Cells(i, 15) >= 0 And Cells(i, 11) = "No Action Pending" Then
        Cells(i, 17) = "Pending with employee"
        Else
        If Cells(i, 10).Value = "No" And Cells(i, 15) >= 0 And Cells(i, 11) = "Pending With Manager" Then
        Cells(i, 17) = "Pending with Manager"
        Else
        If Cells(i, 10).Value = "Yes" And Cells(i, 15) >= 0 And Cells(i, 11) = "No Action Pending" Then
        Cells(i, 17) = "All Done"
        
        'If Not IsEmpty(.Cells(i, "B").Value) Then
         ' If .Cells(i, "E").Value = "NA" Then'
         'ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("CTCto TCC Conversion").Cells(i, "F").Value = "NA" '
         
                End If
         
         End If
         End If
          End If
          
        Next i
        
    End With
        MsgBox "Column Created"
 End Sub
```

It throws me an error Invalid or unqualified reference .Please help me if there any errors that need to be rectified for the code to run .

Thanks

Comment: You need a `With ...` statement for `.Cells` and `.Rows.Count` to refer to. Or remove the `.` in front of those calls to implicitly refer to the `ActiveSheet`, which is what you do elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

### Using the `With` Statement

- BigBen has already answered your question. Here's an example with a little extra.
- Check the two lines containing `.Cells(i, 15).Value`. One of them should probably have the equal sign removed.
- If you write several conditions in one line of code, all of them will be evaluated even if the first one is already `True` (or `False`) making it less efficient than writing each condition in a new line. In practice, you most often won't feel a difference. I cannot decide which one is more readable or maintainable for you though.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Button2_Click()

    With Sheet1
        Dim i As Long
        For i = 2 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
            If .Cells(i, 10).Value = "No" Then
                If .Cells(i, 15).Value <= 0 Then
                    .Cells(i, 17).Value = "Pending with employee"
                Else
                    If .Cells(i, 11).Value = "No Action Pending" Then
                        .Cells(i, 17).Value = "Pending with employee"
                    ElseIf .Cells(i, 11).Value = "Pending With Manager" Then
                        .Cells(i, 17).Value = "Pending with Manager"
                    End If
                End If
            ElseIf .Cells(i, 10).Value = "Yes" Then
                If .Cells(i, 15).Value >= 0 Then
                    If .Cells(i, 11).Value = "No Action Pending" Then
                        .Cells(i, 17).Value = "All Done"
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Next i
    End With
    
    MsgBox "Column Created"

End Sub
```